# Python: Count the consecutive characters at the beginning of a string

Tags: python

I want to count how many leading repeat characters at the beginning of a string. So far the code I wrote:

```
def count_characters(s, target):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == target:
            counter += 1
        else:
            return counter
```

It works.  Now I just curious if there is a simpler way to get it done in one or two lines instead of writing an extra function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you strip the characters from the beginning, then you are left with a shorter string and can subtract its length from the original, giving you the number of characters removed.

`return len(s) - len(s.lstrip(target))`

---

Note: Your shown code will immediately return 0 if the first character does not match `target`. If you want to check if there is *any* repeated first character, you don't need to have `target` and can just use `s[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `next` and a `range`:

```
return next(i+1 for i in range(len(s)) if s[i] != s[0], len(s))
```

Comment: I am not sure this will return the correct answer if there are no other characters in the string.